# Cannot boot both windows and ubuntu anymore due to wrong partition processes. How do i fix this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, lenovo

Here is my story: I have decided to format my windows 8.1 with "onekey recovery" button of my Lenovo Ideapad Z510. When completed, i have no problems about windows, however grub2 have been lost. 
Then i have started to fixing my grub because i have not lost my ubuntu yet. I have tried a lot, but i couldn't. Then i have decided to install ubuntu 14.04.1 again, and i have done it. 
I have used my computer as i want for 1 day, the pc starts with grub2, then i choose windows or ubuntu etc..
Then, suddenly, when i have restarted my windows, grub2 have not came, i couldnt understand whats wrong. Then have i started ubuntu live on my usb again and tried to solve via terminal codes. 
I followed instructions from internet, i mounted some drives etc. etc. then i hang about looking for codes for unmounting them.

I have started to install ubuntu again, installer gave an error again ( we have found unmounted drives etc. should we unmount them etc.) i clicked yes then i have been shocked!

http://i.hizliresim.com/jv8oYD.png

There are only 5 partitions now, which was 8-9 before. And as you see, somethings are going very bad!

I have tried to solve this with "onekey recovery" button again, which gives me (like)"cannot find files" error now. I think i permanently deleted recovery files of windows, and deleted windows boot mgr (because it doesnt appear).

I'll check for my lenovo's warranty service,but am not sure they will fix this.

What do you think, can i solve this problem or i have just turned into my pc a basic-calculator? Did i kill it?

I am now enjoying my live ubuntu :D (sorry for grammar etc. mistakes )

Note: my pictures, videos etc. are not important for me,, im just looking for save my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Possibilities:

1. Contact Lenovo Turkey and ask them for a "Recovery DVD" (Depending on the vendor, they will do this for free, charge just Shipping&Handling, or charge you a lot)
2. Delete all partitions, create 1 `swap` partition with size equal to twice your RAM, create a 64 GB `/` partition and a 1TB `/home` partition and install Ubuntu with all its updates.  Then install wine under Ubuntu and forget Windows ever existed. (which is how I'm running now)

(yes, that's not all of your disk: keep the rest as "spare" to add wherever you want in a few years time)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 6 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: oh thank you, i have called lenovo turkey and they sent me 3 dvd's from ireland in 2 weeks, i have just inserted discs and clicked next buttons and everything is fine now, and they didn't want any money. Thanks for advise :)